# What happens to imports and package names when a Go program is compiled

Tags: go

Once a go program is compiled, is there any way one can extract the name of the packages (as later explained in the question) if the machine code is decompiled to Assembly (or then to C)?

In go we generally import packages by providing a link to the repo (if open source). For example `github.com/abc/abc`. This is means that the username of the library developer is usually part of the package import. Now, when the program is compiled, what happens to them? Can they be somehow extracted from the compiled binary?

Generally speaking, in think the compiler should put the whole code in one place and then it can get rid of those names, but I am unsure about it. That is why I asked the question. I asked this question because in one special case if that package import is somehow included in the binary, it will lead to a serious security problem.

Answer (score -1):

After some investigation, I found that Go does include these in the binary. I opened the binary in a text editor and I tried to look up repo names. At the end of the file, there is a big text portion which includes a lot of textual information. The names of repos used in the program can also be simply looked up.

This means that if you are working on security projects where you need to hide as much information as possible, you need to somehow be careful about these.

Comment: Yep. You can also run the `strings` command on the binary. In addition, the package names stay there even if you strip the binary with `-ldflags="-s -w"`.